# Only null values when using bulkloader

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I am using a bulkloader.yaml, which worked months ago, on new data I have to upload in the database of a Google App Engine web app. The problem is that it is creating rows with null values.

I have therefore tried to generate a new yaml file from the current database, as described here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata,  and use it as new configuration file for the bulkloader.

Still null rows are created

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the CSV files lacked of a header line!